# yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping

Tags: centos7, yaml, patroni

I followed this document while configuring patroni and I have a problem with patroni.service file like this
https://snapshooter.com/learn/postgresql/postgresql-cluster-patroni

```
[Unit]
Description=Runners to orchestrate a high-availability PostgreSQL
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple

User=postgres
Group=postgres

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/patroni /etc/patroni.yml

KillMode=process

TimeoutSec=30

Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.targ
```

Here is my patroni.yml

```
scope: postgres
namespace: /db/
name: etcd1

restapi:
    listen: 10.102.196.138:8008
    connect_address: 10.102.196.138:8008

etcd:
    hosts: 10.102.196.138:2379,10.102.196.139:2379,10.102.196.147:2379

bootstrap:
    dcs:
        ttl: 30
        loop_wait: 10
        retry_timeout: 10
        maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
        postgresql:
            use_pg_rewind: true

    initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - data-checksums

    pg_hba:
    - host replication all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host replication all 10.102.196.138/0 md5
    - host replication all 10.102.196.139/0 md5
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

    users:
        admin:
            password: admin
            options:
                - createrole
                - createdb
 postgresql:
    listen: 10.102.196.138:5432
    connect_address: 10.102.196.138:5432
    data_dir: /data/patroni
    pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
    authentication:
        replication:
            username: replicator
            password: password
        superuser:
            username: postgres
            password: password
    parameters:
        unix_socket_directories: '.'

tags:
    nofailover: false
    noloadbalance: false
    clonefrom: false
    nosync: false
```

And I got this error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo systemctl status patroni -l
● patroni.service - Runners to orchestrate a high-availability PostgreSQL
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/patroni.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-05-24 23:24:26 +07; 7s ago
  Process: 3307 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/patroni /etc/patroni.yml (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3307 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 24 23:24:26 localhost.localdomain patroni[3307]: self.current_event = self.state()
May 24 23:24:26 localhost.localdomain patroni[3307]: File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 439, in parse_block_mapping_key
May 24 23:24:26 localhost.localdomain patroni[3307]: "expected <block end>, but found %r" % token.id, token.start_mark)
May 24 23:24:26 localhost.localdomain patroni[3307]: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
May 24 23:24:26 localhost.localdomain patroni[3307]: in "/etc/patroni.yml", line 1, column 1
May 24 23:24:26 localhost.localdomain patroni[3307]: expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
May 24 23:24:26 localhost.localdomain patroni[3307]: in "/etc/patroni.yml", line 38, column 2
May 24 23:24:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: patroni.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 24 23:24:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit patroni.service entered failed state.
May 24 23:24:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: patroni.service failed.
```

Comment: It says the error is in /etc/patroni.yml.

Comment: i have just updated my /etc/patroni.yml file, can u have a look?

Comment: The only issue I could find is the space in front of postgresql on line 37. Try pasting it into a parser/linter such as https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator or http://www.yamllint.com/. At yamllint.com, I can reproduce your error until I fix line 37.